# Redirecting main domain to another

Tags: seo, local-seo

Running new site on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS.

I have a domain which i have had for several years and is registered with search engines and is hosted with "Host 1", for this example i will call it

https://www.example.com

I have a second domain https://www.newexample.com which is brand new and is on Host 2.

If i do a redirect from https://www.example.com to https://www.newexample.com would this kill the existing SEO (for https://www.example.com) even if i have the same named pages?

Feel free to ask more questions if this doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is they way the site is constructed to make its content understandable to web engines. The new site can have better or worse SEO score, depending on if best practices were followed while constructing it.

I am assuming you are talking about search engine ranking. What you need to do is set up a 301 ("moved permanently") redirection on the server you are using. All new requests for `www.example.com` will be redirected to `www.newexample.com` and at the same time you will be signalling to search engines that the content of the request was moved permanently to a new URL.

Given some time, all the ranking of your old site will be redirected to your new site.

Comment: Thanks! and yes search ranking. So to confirm if i place a normal 301 redirect on the old site if anyone decides to visit the original URL /somepage/someinnerpage then this would go to New URL /somepage/someinnerpage? Even if its going from one https to another complete different named https domain?

Comment: @Computer You would have to set up the rules but yes, this is the point of 301 redirection. The simplest redirection rule would be "if a user asks for a page in domain A, redirect to the same page of domain B", which is what you described. The rule would have to apply to all pages that are requested from the old domain, not just for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

An older domain has more authority than new one if the older one was active and getting good traffic.

> If i do a redirect from https://www.example.com to
>   https://www.newexample.com would this kill the existing SEO (for
>   https://www.example.com) even if i have the same named pages?

However, **this will not kill your website's SEO if you're going to implement 301 redirect** to your older domains **.htaccess** file (ask developer to help you out, don't try yourself if you're not familiar with this file)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Same thing you've to do with your old domains pages as well such that they can pass link juice or SEO effectively.

It would be good if I can see your sites and go through them to suggest you the appropriate solution nevertheless go through the solution as stated, to have it all in your new domain.

Answer (score -2):

No it would never kill or affect the SEO for site one https://example.com.
Redirect it to website two.
Using js

```
<script>windows.location = "http://newsite.com/";</script>
```

Plus point is your new site ranking will also be increased by redirecting it to new domain.

Comment: Why use JavaScript for this when there are better ways to do it?

Comment: Well it's just an example. There are many ways to do that. You can do it in php to, from cpanel too. The Question is SEO affect <-. So there is a technique "Expire Domains". We buy high DA expire domains and redirect it to our site which increase our ranking and get google trust.